# Splitting a string using special characters and keeping them

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a string with special characters and not being able to split the parentheses properly.
This the code I'm trying :

```
class Ione
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String str = "g, i+, w+ | (d | (u+, f))+"; 
        String[] chunks = str.split(",\\s+|(?=\\W)");
        for(int q=0; q<chunks.length; q++) {
          System.out.println(""+chunks[q]);   
       } 
    }
}
```

The regex does not split the starting parentheses `(`

I'm trying to get the following output:

```
g,i,+,w,+,|,(,d,|,(,u,+,f,),),+
```

Could someone please help me. Thank you.

[image: output of the code]

Comment: It is not clear what output do you get. Please include it in your question.

Comment: @DYZ I've attached the image of the output.

Comment: Please past the text of the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to use `split()` to get every character separately, except for spaces and commas, so split by spaces/commas and by "nothing", i.e. the zero-width "space" between non-space/comma characters.

```java
String str = "g, i+, w+ | (d | (u+, f))+";
String[] chunks = str.split("[\\s,]+|(?<![\\s,])(?![\\s,])");
System.out.println(String.join(",", chunks));
```

*Output*

```
g,i,+,w,+,|,(,d,|,(,u,+,f,),),+
```

---

**Alternative:** Search for what you want, and collect it into an array or `List` *(requires Java 9)*:

```java
String str = "g, i+, w+ | (d | (u+, f))+";
String[] chunks = Pattern.compile("[^\\s,]").matcher(str).results()
        .map(MatchResult::group).toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(String.join(",", chunks));
```

Same output.

For older versions of Java, use a `find()` loop:

```java
String str = "g, i+, w+ | (d | (u+, f))+";
List<String> chunkList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^\\s,]").matcher(str); m.find(); )
    chunkList.add(m.group());
System.out.println(chunkList);
```

*Output*

```
[g, i, +, w, +, |, (, d, |, (, u, +, f, ), ), +]
```

You can always convert the `List` to an array:

```java
String[] chunks = chunkList.toArray(new String[0]);
```